# Prevent div collapsing if child min-with set

Tags: html, css, dom, width

I have the following markup:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: #000;
        }

        .wrapper {
            min-width: 1000px;
            background: #f00;
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="problem-div">
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I resize the browser window DIV.problem-div takes the body, html or viewport with (I dont know exactly). What i need is to make that div to take width of its child (.wrapper) without setting its min-width or making it positioned absolute. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are block level elements that will always have a width of 100%.  Set the display property to inline-block and that should get you the desired result.

```
.problem-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You made my night :) Thanks